# scala futures - keeping track of request context when threadId is irrelevant

Tags: scala, logging, promise, future

making first steps using Scala promises/futures in a web server (still Jetty/synchronous for now :( ), as expected the threadId is no longer useful for tracking what happened during a single HTTP request processing.

I guess logging a request token will do the trick - is this the recommended approach? if so can you refer me to some code already doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach in such situation is to have a case class that holds contextual data (such as request id) and pass it throught all layers of your application as `implicit` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

pardon me for adding an answer, but I just saw this relevant idea published on scala times (http://scalatimes.com/):
http://www.schibsted.pl/blog/tracing-back-scala-future-chains/
the gist of it -
wrap Future with TraceableFuture which adds the "future stack".